# TypeError: DataType float32 for attr 'T' not in list of allowed values: int32, int64

Tags: python, tensorflow

hallo i am trying to run the code using Anaconda but i got this error even i have already run the program using cpu in another pc , its worked fine. may be because using python v3.5 and in the other pc python v2.5 ?

i created screenshot for the error [image]

the error line is that

```
with graph.as_default() :     
  w_b_not = {
      'weight_4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden, num_labels], stddev=0.1), name = 'weight_4'),
      'bias_4'  : tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[num_labels]), name = 'bias_4')}
```

Comment: `num_hidden` and `num_labels` should both be integers

Comment: but this code is already worked on another computer using cpu why on Gpu not working ?

Comment: maybe there's some difference in GPU kernel registrations, you can try to run without gpu by doing `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=` before running your script on the gpu machine