# DataType float32 for attr 'T' not in list of allowed values: int32, int64

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have considered these two posts([this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41662727/3768871) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44481437/3768871)), but they are not my problem and solution. I have the following code to create a feed forward network in tf:

```
step = 500
fromState = 0
toState = 5000000
numOfState = (toState - fromState) / step
numOfAction = 11

tf.reset_default_graph()
inputs1 = tf.placeholder(shape=[1,numOfState], dtype = tf.float32)
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([numOfState,4],0,0.01),)
Qout = tf.matmul(inputs1,W)
predict = tf.argmax(Qout,1)
```

However, I've got the following error in this line `Qout = tf.matmul(inputs1,W)`:

> TypeError: DataType float32 for attr 'T' not in list of allowed values: int32, int64

Apparently everything is ok, but the question is what is this error and where does it come from?

Comment: Just keep ints :  (toState - fromState) // step

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the problem. The  problem comes from `numOfState`. As I have found its type is `float32`. Hence, the problem is solved by casting this variable to int:

```
#numOfState = (toState - fromState) / step 
# change to
numOfState = int((toState - fromState) / step)
```